# Splitting a string based on angle brackets?

Tags: java, regex, scala

Is there any way to split a string into sections based on angle brackets, so

`1<2>3<4>` should become `["1", "<2>", "3", "<4>"]`.

I've tried `"1<2>3<4>".split("<([^>]*)>")` but that only gives me `["1", "3"]`

Comment: Regular expressions cannot count.  Find another solution.

Comment: When you split a string on a delimiter, the delimiter is NOT part of the split string. If you split a string on the angle bracket, how are you expecting the angle bracket in the split string.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Count what?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen the question (presumably?) doesn't involve balancing nested brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With lookaheads:

```
scala> val s = "1<2>3<4>"
scala> s.split("(?=<)|(?<=>)")
res6: Array[String] = Array(1, <2>, 3, <4>)
```

See `(?=X)` and `(?<=X)` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to split before an open bracket or after a close bracket:

```
(?=<)|(?<=>)
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/7cBd1R/1)

Answer (score 1):

Regex find on regular numbers, or those with brackets around them

```
scala> """\d+|(<\d+>)""".r.findAllIn("1<2>3<4>").toArray
res0: Array[String] = Array(1, <2>, 3, <4>)
```

Can also do `"""<?\d+>?""".r`